# Bash access property loaded from a properties files with a variable

Tags: bash, shell

let's say we have a properties file: myprops.properties
with the following key pair values:

- test_user=myuser
- test_hostip=myip
- uat_user=myuser2

In my script I wrote these lines:

```
_ENVIRONMENT="test" 
. myprops.properties # load the properties
```

> I would like to access the user property starting with $_ENVIRONMENT i.e."test"

_USER=$_ENVIRONMENT"_user" # this does not work it outputs "testuser" which is the key and not the value.

If I declare:

```
echo ${testuser} # that works I get the value
```

What I am missing? Is it possible?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006 for lots of information about this general topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use indirect variable reference:

```
varUser="${_ENVIRONMENT}_user"
echo "${!varUser}"
myuser
```

Comment: If it worked out, you may mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.

Comment: I did when I wrote my response yesterday.